# Why does retagging take 200 reputation when I can edit the entire post with only 100?

Tags: bug, reputation

Today I crossed the 200-reputation threshold, and received a notification that I'm now allowed to re-tag posts.  This is confusing, because I had edited 6 or 7 questions before today and was able to update the title, text, and tags.

Am I missing something here?  Shouldn't the ability to re-tag come before the ability to edit the entire question?

Comment: Editing the entire post may have happened at 150 instead of 100, or at some other level... I wasn't paying attention at the time, but it was definitely a few days ago.

Comment: During the private beta a lot of rep requirements were drastically less than now.

Comment: I only joined a week ago, so I don't think it was that.

Answer (score 4):

At 100 reputation, you can only edit *community wiki* posts. Posts are made community wiki in exceptional situations where the wider-spread editing is desired. That's why it has the lower reputation requirements.

In the normal use case, **editing other people's posts requires 1,000 reputation.**

From the faq — [What is reputation?](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/faq#reputation)

> ```
> 15      Vote up
> 15      Flag for moderator attention
> 50      Leave comments†
> 100     Edit community wiki posts
> 125     Vote down (costs 1 rep on answers)
> 150     Create new tags
> 200     Reduced advertising
> 200     Retag questions
> 250     Vote to close, reopen, or migrate your questions
> 500     Vote to close, reopen, or migrate any questions
> 750     Show total up and down vote counts
> 1000    Edit other people’s posts, vote to approve or reject suggested edits
> 1500    Vote to approve or reject suggested tag wiki edits
> 2000    Vote to delete closed questions, access to moderation tools
> 3500    Protect questions so only registered users with 10 rep on this site can answer
> 4000    Vote to delete negatively voted answers and stronger question deletion votes
> ```

*Note — These are the reduced reputation requirements that are in effect during the public beta.*

Comment: It definitely wasn't community wiki posts that I edited.  Maybe I'm confusing the ability to edit posts with the ability to submit changes **that must be approved by someone else**.  Is that a possibility?  If so, the faq might be made clearer... robotics is my first experience with stackexchange, so maybe this affects me more than long-time stackexchange users.

Comment: Hmm... Nothing comes to mind. Suggested edits are allowed at 1-rep and the private beta allows full editing at 500.